# How to reproduce sound from binary data identical to the original

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I get binary data like -0.00005645725104856084 and 0.00000906579771242124 (-1 to 1 range) using the method available from here: https://gist.github.com/maxogden/3786030

Then I send them to a server for further processing with a method available from http://ncthompson.com/blog/2013/01/07/you-dont-need-that-scriptprocessor/ to regenerate sound identical to the original tones on the other end.

However, all I can get is ear-splitting white noise and Aw, Snap! on Chrome. Did I do it the wrong way?

Anyone know any methods or ways that should get this process working?

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project below demonstrates this is possible:

```
http://agektmr.node-ninja.com:3000/
```